# Predefine a generic in java

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should you encapsulate generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241592/when-should-you-encapsulate-generic-types)

I've started with using Generics in java but I ran into a big problem with defining them because my code gets rapidly unreadable like in the case of:

```
PriorityQueue<Vertex<Integer, VertexValue, Integer, EdgeValue>> Q = new PriorityQueue<Vertex<Integer, VertexValue, Integer, EdgeValue>>(10, new AugPathPQSuperawesomeComparator());
```

And there are multiple instances of this piece of code.

Is there a way to make it all smaler by using something like:

```
V = Vertex<Integer, VertexValue, Integer, EdgeValue>
PriorityQueue<V> Q = new PriorityQueue<V>(10, new AugPathPQSuperawesomeComparator());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like.

```
class VPrioQueue<EV> extends PriorityQueue<Vertex<Integer, VertexValue, Integer, EV>> {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define your own type, like

```
class MyContainer {
  Vertex<Integer, VertexValue, Integer, EdgeValue> myComplexElt = new ...;

  // define methods for this class
  // using eclipse source->generate delegate methods
}
```

You can also inherit the type, but it is usially a worse idea.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick and easy way to make the statement somewhat smaller without introducing an additional type:

Since Java 1.7, there is the diamond operator which lets you skip the statement of the types in the assignment. So you can refactor your code to:

```
PriorityQueue<Vertex<Integer, VertexValue, Integer, EdgeValue>> Q = new PriorityQueue<>(10, new AugPathPQSuperawesomeComparator());
```